# Confused by AngularJS ng-repeat syntax

Tags: angularjs, syntax, directive, plural, singular

What is the meaning of the singular/plural syntax in, say, `ng-repeat="product in store.products"`?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: `product` has nothing to do with `store.products`.  You could write `blahblah` in `store.products`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does ng-repeat work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133429/how-does-ng-repeat-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Singular/plural is used just for common sense and code readability - it doesn't have to be singular/plural. You can do

```
ng-repeat="whatever in store.products"`
```

and then have the `whatever` object available inside (like: `<img ng-src="{{whatever.images[0]}}" />`).

In your case, `store.products` can't be changed since it refers to an actual object, while `product` is a completely custom name to be used in the repeat loop.

Fairly common in programming. Like the other answer said, it's similar to the for..in syntax.

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially the same syntax as a Javascript [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). It means for `someTempVar in someArrayOrObject`.

Answer (score 3):

The directive `ng-repeat="product in products"` creates a new variable `product` that you can reference inside your template. There is no singular/plural interpolation going on.