# Why track by $index is necessary for ng-click to trigger inside nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I was using `ng-click` inside the nested `ng-repeat` but found that the inner most ng-click(3rd level) was not getting triggered.
But when I used `track by $index` for the inner most ng-repeat, ng-click got triggered.
I am not able to understand this behavior of nested ng-repeat.

Please find below the code snippet

```
<ul class="a">
    <li class="b" ng-repeat="items in Objects track by $index" ng-click="callSomething()">
        <a>{{items.name}}</a>
        <ul class="c">
            <li class="d" ng-repeat="items1 in Objects1 track by $index" ng-click="callSomething()">
                <a>{{items1.name}}</a>
                <ul class="e">
                    <li class="f" ng-repeat="items2 in Objects3 track by $index" ng-click="callSomething()">
                        <a>{{items3.name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if you want to get to the bottom of this, please post your objects and callSomething function. my simple test worked fine. also please note, that when you click on the inner most element, you're calling callSomething three times, unless you stop the event propagation. or you can use this to your advantage and handle all events on the top level only (skip the inner ng-clicks, that's called delegation).

Comment: Sorry Oleg i cannot post the object and the method due to the confidentiality reason. But my object has very simple structure (id,name,childObject) and callSomething only filter data on the object selection

Comment: there may be a difference in how you get the actual element you clicked. you can either pass the id directly (like `callSomething(items.id)` or pass an event (`callSomething($event)` and later in `callSomething(e){e.target)` etc). track by is actually used by ng-repeat to keep an eye on changes and rebuild the structure, and if it's not set explictlly it still has some kind of internal ID.

Comment: @PranjalDiwedi You don't have to post the actual data, you can post some dummy data of similar structure. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Its really related to ng-repeat behavior. Each element is tracked uniquely and mapped to the scope. I think this thread already answers your questions:

[How does ng-repeat work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133429/how-does-ng-repeat-work)