# How to iterate videos and Sliders in angular js using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have videos and images I want to keep it as sliders for that i have to iterate it, without hard coding the images and videos .

Comment: Just use [ngRepeat directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does ng-repeat work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133429/how-does-ng-repeat-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array and put your files in the array using an angular controller or services whatever you like. In your html use the ng-repeat directive to loop over the array and do what you like with individual elements. The code should look like this (only for demonstration purpose):

```
// I did this to display my images in html you can do 
// similar thing for videos
<div ng-repeat="image in images">  // images is the array which holds images sources
    <img src="{[{image.src}]}>  
</div>
```